# Android SoftKeyboard: Shiftkey to load another keyboad layout

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, custom-keyboard

I have two files where I have android KeyCodes: `Qwerty.xml` and `numbers.xml`. On any press of <kbd>shift</kbd> key, I want the numeric keypad to be displayed.

### Java Class:

```
public class MyKeyboard extends InputMethodService
                        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
{
    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        //keyboard = new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty1);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        switch (primaryCode){
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
                caps = !caps;
                keyboard.setShifted(caps);
                kv.invalidateAllKeys();
                break;
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
                ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
                break;
            default:
                char code = (char) primaryCode;
                if (Character.isLetter(code) && caps) {
                   code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                }
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
}
```

Is there any method that I can call from `case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT` in order to load `numbers.xml` file to display numeric keypad?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your

```
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
```

to

```
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.numbers);
            kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            break;
```

Or add in to your qwerty.xml the shift keycode to eg. -1 and add this to your java class

```
            case -1:
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.number);
            kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit both `Qwerty.xml` and `numbers.xml` file and assign custom keyCode to shift key. For example: The keyCode of shift key is `120000`.

Make an instance of `LatinKeyboard`:

```
private LatinKeyboard numbersKeyboard;
```

And add logic to the following method (`SoftKeyboard.java`):

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
.....

if (primaryCode == 120000) {
    mInputView.setKeyboard(numbersKeyboard);
}

...
```